# Play Framework Form Submission

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have followed the java play framework tutorial and created the todo task list that is the result of this tutorial:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTodoList

I wanted to modify this project slightly so that instead of having label input the form I had two other inputs, starting location and end location.

Firstly I included the extra variables I required in the java class in *Models/*

```
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String starting_location;

    @Required
    public String end_location;
```

I also added this to the index.scala.html file:

```
@form(routes.Application.newJourney()) {

    @inputText(journeyForm("Starting Location"))
    @inputText(journeyForm("End Location")) 
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
}
```

I get the form fields "Starting Location" and "End Location" displaying as expected but when I click on submit the total number of journeys (or tasks for as described in the play example) does not increment and does not get added to the list of current journeys that can be deleted.

Any help is appreciated and I can post full source if required.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper inputText is documented [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputText%24).

You put there a label where the field name should be.

This should work:

```
@inputText(
    journeyForm("starting_location"), 
    '_label -> "Starting Location"
)
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but I marked as correct!

Comment: So I am still having some problems with this. When ever I try and create a form entry I am getting the follow error:

`case controllers_Application_createJourney2(params) => {
  call { 
        invokeHandler(_root_.controllers.Application.createJourney(),   HandlerDef(this, "controllers.Application", "createJourney", Nil))
   }
}
`

Comment: Never mind I stopped the server and did a `play clean` and the issue was resolved. Mildly frustrating :)